# wxWidget wxScrolledWindow cancel previous drawing

Tags: c++, scroll, panel, wxwidgets

I'm trying to get a scrolling panel where I can draw picture like on MS Paint
The problem is that, when I draw something to try the application:

1. I draw one rectangle (or more than one)
2. I scroll the panel to the right, the rectangles remain to the left
3. I scroll the panel to the left, the rectangles are disappeared

I'm a newbie in wx and I think I'm missing something important
Using wxWidget in Codelite (C++), Windows 7 32 bit
That's the code:

**editorshp.h**

```
class EditorShp : public wxFrame {
    protected:
        wxClientDC *dcPannelloDisegno;
        wxScrolledWindow *scrollwin;
        wxPanel *pannello;

    public:
        EditorShp( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxString& title = _("Editor SHP"), const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxSize( 800,500 ), long style = wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );

        void draw_temp(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event));
    };
```

**editorshp.cpp**
PS: bDrawTemp is the button I use for drawing some rectangles (the first is at point 100,100; the second at 200,100 and so on)

```
EditorShp::EditorShp( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxFrame( parent, id, title, pos, size, style ) {

    scrollwin = new wxScrolledWindow(this, -1, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(700, 400));
    scrollwin->SetScrollbars(1, 1, 1600, 1000, 0, 0);

    pannello = new wxPanel(scrollwin, -1, wxPoint(0, 0), wxSize(700, 400), wxFULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE);
    dcPannelloDisegno = new wxClientDC(pannello);
    scrollwin->DoPrepareDC(*dcPannelloDisegno);

    wxButton *bDrawTemp= new wxButton( this, wxID_ANY, _("Indietro"), wxPoint(0, 400), wxSize( 100, 24 ), 0 );
    bDrawTemp->Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(EditorShp::disegnaTemp), NULL, this);

    scrollwin->Show(true);
    this->Show(true);
}

void EditorShp::draw_temp(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event)){
    static int x = 100, y = 100;

    dcPannelloDisegno->DrawRectangle(wxPoint(x, y), wxSize(10, 10));
    //pannello->Refresh(); it cancels everything
    pannello->Update();

    x += 100;
    x = x % 1600;
}
```

**EDIT 1:** Sorry it's not wxScrollingPanel but **wxScrolledWindow**

Comment: Nothing happens if I add wxBufferedDC connected to the wxClientDC... do I have to use a wxPaintDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, catch `wxEVT_PAINT` and do the drawing in its hadler, using a `wxPaintDC` (or one of its variants - `wx[Auto]BufferedPaintDC`).
Second, you are now attempting to paint on `pannello`, and for that you do not need to prepare the `wxDC`. However, from your description you want to paint on `scrollwin`, and in that case you might not even need `pannello`.

So, for drawing on a scrolled window, see `scroll` sample that comes with wxW. What you probably need is the implementation of `MySimpleCanvas` (described as `a scrolled window which draws a simple rectangle`) - to see it press `F1` when running the sample.

As a general rule, the samples should be the first place to search for a functionality; there are a lot of them exemplified there.

Comment: thank you :) I don't understand much on how really works that, but now it seems to work (following the example). Thanks again